# How to remove an event listener in EaselJS object

Tags: javascript, events, easeljs

I use CreateJS/EaselJS to create a canvas example. I have a card object (bitmap object), and I add to it an event listener to handle 'mousedown' event. Then I try to remove this event listener, but it seem it is not working. Can anyone help me?

```
toggleDragDrop: function (stage, state) {
            if (state) {
                this.graphicsObj.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
                    var offset = { x: evt.target.x - evt.stageX, y: evt.target.y - evt.stageY };

                    // add a handler to the event object's onMouseMove callback
                    // this will be active until the user releases the mouse button:
                    evt.addEventListener("mousemove", function (ev) {
                        ev.target.x = ev.stageX + offset.x;
                        ev.target.y = ev.stageY + offset.y;
                        stage.update();
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                this.graphicsObj.removeEventListener("mousedown");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.removeEventListener()` requires *two* (or three) arguments, not just one. The second argument is a reference to the same listener function that was passed into `.addEventListener()`. So you can't use an anonymous function expression with `.addEventListener()` if you want to remove it later. Instead, use a named function so you can refer to it in both calls:

```
toggleDragDrop: function (stage, state) {
    function downer( evt ) {
        var offset = {
            x: evt.target.x - evt.stageX,
            y: evt.target.y - evt.stageY
        };

        // add a handler to the event object's onMouseMove callback
        // this will be active until the user releases the mouse button
        evt.addEventListener("mousemove", function (ev) {
            ev.target.x = ev.stageX + offset.x;
            ev.target.y = ev.stageY + offset.y;
            stage.update();
        });
    }

    if (state) {
        this.graphicsObj.addEventListener("mousedown", downer);
    }
    else {
        this.graphicsObj.removeEventListener("mousedown", downer);
    }
}
```